# Logging in ASP.NET web application from external library

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

I have library with log functionality and ASP.NET web application, which uses this library. I need to write logs to web application folder. If I write logs from web app, I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath`, but how can I get path of current web application from external lib? Thank you.

Comment: What library are you using? Are you talking about reading or writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, for example in your Global.asax's `Application_Start` method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    YourLogLibrary.StaticLogConfiguration.LogDirectory = Server.MapPath("~/Logs");
}
```